How can I check my .emacs file for legacy functions?
Recently I did
(describe-function 'global-unset-key) and saw,

This is a legacy function; see ... for the
recommended function to use instead.

Holy smokes, that's just the tip of the iceberg. My .emacs file it turns out is chock full of legacy functions! How to check it? Please don't tell me:

One function and variable at a time, just like you did.

Nothing fancy please, like auto-checking every 33 days. Just some one-shot method I might use once in a while.
Yes, my .emacs file hasn't started producing any actual errors, or even just warnings... yet.

You should be able to find them all by byte-compiling the file. Do C-h f make-obsolete for more details. Untested.

... but you won't find global-unset-key:  make-obsolete has not been called on it. Instead. the doc string of the function has been modified to say what you saw.
